# IronPython DLR not working on Mono (Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, linux, mono, ironpython

I've got a problem when trying to run my simple console application written in C#/Mono using IronPython. When I run it on Windows 7 SP1 64bit, there're absolutely no problems with it. However, when I try to run it on Ubuntu with one of the newest Mono versions installed (I've successfuly tested many C#/Mono applications on it before), it won't run. Full debug which I received using `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug` is below this text:

```
tomsontom@ubuntu:~$ MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe'
Mono: gc took 75 usecs
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0xd14930] -> /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll[0xd13cb0]: 2
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.so: /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0xd14930] added to domain IronPythonConsole.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/tomsontom/.mono/config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe'.
Mono: Image addref IronPythonConsole[0xd91670] -> /mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe[0xd12b70]: 3
Mono: Assembly IronPythonConsole[0xd91670] added to domain IronPythonConsole.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe.so: /mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/IronPythonConsole/IronPythonConsole.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe'.
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe.so: /mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Ref addref IronPythonConsole[0xd91670] -> mscorlib[0xd14930]: 2
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe.config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Scripting/1.1.0.20__7f709c5b713576e1/Microsoft.Scripting.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/Microsoft.Scripting.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/Microsoft.Scripting.dll'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Scripting/1.1.0.20__7f709c5b713576e1/Microsoft.Scripting.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/Microsoft.Scripting.exe'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/Microsoft.Scripting.exe'.
Mono: The following assembly referenced from /mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/IronPythonConsole.exe could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   Microsoft.Scripting    (assemblyref_index=2)
     Version:    1.1.0.20
     Public Key: 7f709c5b713576e1
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/mnt/hgfs/Mono Shared/ironpython/).

Mono: Failed to load assembly IronPythonConsole[0xd91670]

Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.1.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of its dependencies.

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.1.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.1.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.1.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.1.0.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1'
```

As you can see, Mono is complaining about `Microsoft.Scripting` library. However, **it is** located in the same directory as the executable! I've also tried copying some other libraries, but nothing helped me. Right now, these files are in the same folder:

```
IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
IronPythonConsole.exe
Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata.dll
```

What could be the problem here? I've read that IronPython should work on Mono without any problems. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, it definitely should work with recent Mono. Do the referenced and present libraries not differ in casing?

Comment: Btw, you can also try using the newest IronPython libraries (on Linux and Windows) which can be downloaded here: http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/62475#DownloadId=295580